# Typescript is not able to provide type safety to a simple reducer

Tags: typescript

I have a simple reducer that uses an object to accumulate values. I wanted to use as much TS inference as possible.
However I am not able to make typescript provide proper type safety. It rather complains wrongly, because the empty object does not contain any of the expected types, or if I type the object it does not complain at all (while some keys may lead to an undefined value).

So given this code:

```js
type Session = { name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date };
type SessionGroup = {
  name: string;
  duration: number;
  sessions: Session[];
};
type Grouped = { [k: string]: SessionGroup };

function selectGroupedSessions(sessions: Session[]): SessionGroup[] {
  const grouped = sessions.reduce((result: Grouped, session) => {
    const { name, startDate, endDate } = session;
    const group = result[name] || { name, sessions: [] };
    group.sessions.push(session);
    result[name] = group;
    return result;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(grouped);
}
```

As you can see, I have the accumulator typed as `Grouped`. If I do that it doesn't give me an error on this line: `result[name] = group` but it should because I'm assigning a default value that is not compatible with the expected type of `SessionGroup`. The problem is obviously the `Grouped` type that says that, for every possible string key there is a SessionGroup, which is obviously not true.

If I type the Grouped type like this:

```js
type Grouped = { [k: string]: SessionGroup | undefined };
```

Then I get the following type error on the last line (the return Object.values)

```js
Type '(SessionGroup | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'SessionGroup[]'
```

So, what is the best way to type this to make typescript understand what it's obviously correct JS code? Without adding a ridiculous amount of castings

[Here is a link to a typescript repl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdlAvFA3lNAhgLYQBcU8wATkmgOYDcFwBVwAIgcGVJ90xDQATPj1FQAvgwBQoSLATJ0AcSooArmCy5pUfMR6Ua9GXqHqqXVGnJp1RAEYQqpiouvxycRNYDaAXRkpWXBoVQ1IIW08XwBrciNaOn8vdxU1TUkZaQAzdTQAY2BrNwAbCCLwzQghbyU0eAAKeDSG1J90AIBKdvqqsACdPQL0Sig6DMjtFo6GgDoqGvUCiEbGxfh1UuByfpqAGjdZrqwAPiG9KBGG4Fx9EkPKVg4uCEPBEVfJadbXYdHbhMItoNltgL5CCR-FAAD4wu6Qt5HeqeKCDYKXcaTOYzFFzMDqeAAC2arS6fygoO2EIM0OwQM0FMWwAsGCpwFcEkOOAk5N0lIgLKoGAA8g4AFYVYBzABuBFK6gQjQZkT5wSAA)

Comment: If you turn on [checked indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) it does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKk7GW).  I'm not suggesting that you should necessarily turn that on, but if you do it catches the error in the code above.  Would that work for you?  If so, I'll consider writing up an answer explaining this behavior of index signatures.  If not, please elaborate on what's going on; you say "it complains wrongly" but do not include a [mcve] that shows it, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The explanation of what it means "complaints wrongly" is on that same line. Ideally, I don't want to have to type the accumulator, typescript should be able to infer it from the outer function signature. In the example I provided all you have to do is remove the type annotation of result and you will see the error I'm referring to. Activating the checked indexed access, seems to produce the desired effect, however I'm not sure how it may affect the rest of the codebase. The only drawback I saw is on indexes of arrays, which I never use, so it should be fine.

Comment: Here you have the, minimal reproducible example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdlAvFA3lNAhgLYQBcU8wATkmgOYDcFwBVwAIgcGVJ90xDQATPj1FQAvgwBQoSLATJ0AcSooArmCy5pUfMR6Ua9GXqHqqXVGnJp1RAEYQqpiouvxycRNYDaAXRkpaWkAM3U0AGNgazcAGwho1Q1IIW8lNHgACnh3dE8FH3QAgEovPLRkzQCdPUj84Cg6NU0IIW1cosyAOio29UiILKy++HU44AAaNy6SrAA+Wr0oeszGvEISacpWDi4IacERfckOitc6hqaWrWxR8eBfTYh-KAAfN9x9LZmMgoDpuZLDF0OQAAySC7XFLdTp-bpgdTwAAWOQqJSh9wmTwMr2wzRSmIgwAsGCxwFcEmmOAkGN0UD6JKoGAA8g4AFaJYDdABuBDi6gQWQJrSEdOCQA

Comment: Ah, I see. [Contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) does not work arbitrarily backwards through control flow; and if it did you would get very few errors at all in TypeScript, even for code with obvious problems.  If you write `let i = 0; i = "hello"` you'll get a reasonable error that `"hello"` is not a `number`.  But one could argue that the compiler should use contextual typing to infer that `i` should be, say, `string | number`, since you use it later to store a `string`. I can write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution without activating any extra compiler flags (which could be also a valid answer) is to use a Map instead of an object. Typescript seems to understand that, even if you provide a type for the Map of type `Map<string, SessionGroup>` the get method may return the expected value or undefined. Since nowadays most modern browsers support map, this may be a valid solution. Here is the code that errors out as expected:

```
type Session = { name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date };
type SessionGroup = {
  name: string;
  duration: number;
  sessions: Session[];
};

function selectGroupedSessions(sessions: Session[]): SessionGroup[] {
  const grouped = sessions.reduce((result: Map<string, SessionGroup>, session) => {
    const { name, startDate, endDate } = session;
    const group = result.get(name) || { name, sessions: [], };
    group.sessions.push(session);
    result.set(name, group)
    return result;
  }, new Map());
  return [...grouped.values()]
};
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdlAvFA3lNAhgLYQBcU8wATkmgOYDcFwBVwAIgcGVJ90xDQATPj1FQAvgwBQoSLATJ0AcSooArmCy5pUfMR6Ua9GXqHqqXVGnJp1RAEYQqpiouvxycRNYDaAXRkpaWkAM3U0AGNgazcAGwho1Q1IIW8lNHgACnh3dE8FH3QAgEovPLRkzQCdPUj84Cg6NU0IIW1cosyAOio29UiILKy++HU44HIAWQIwAB4jWjoAGkKMqrAAPlXOjJKsTdq9KHrMxrxCEh2WNlFVwREuaAkOitc6hqaWrWxR8eBunQIMAspcIPsAD4Q3BuLoFALLcyWGLocgABkk7y+KW6uw83TA6ngAAschUSli-hNccDQQZVs0UiVdMc+sALBgqcBXBJVmgIAB3KAzMBZEoUllsjlQXzdOWM1pCboANwIcXUCDF-mkwSAA)